# Why is my API saying fetchAll is not a function?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, bookshelf.js

I had it working with hapi-shelf, but I'm trying to get a jsonapi response and couldn't find way to implement bookshelf-jsonapi-parms with it, so I'm trying the original package for bookshelf.

`TypeError: Uncaught error: Driver.fetchAll is not a function

**server.js**

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require( 'hapi' );
const bodyParser = require( 'body-parser' );


const port = 9200;
const dbConfig = require( './config/config' );
const server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection( {
    port: port,
    routes: {
        cors: true
    }
} );

var knex = require('knex')({
client: 'mysql',
connection: {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "user": "user",
    "password": "pass",
    "database": "db"
}
```

});

```
server.bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

server.start( ( err ) =>{

    if( err ){
        throw err;
    }
    console.log( 'Server running on port ', port );
} );

module.exports = server;

require( './routes' );
```

**models/driver.js**

```
var bookshelf = require('../server').bookshelf;

module.exports = function (bookshelf) {

    var Driver = bookshelf.Model.extend({
        tableName: 'drivers'
    });

    return bookshelf.model('Driver', Driver);
};
```

**controllers/drivers.js**

```
'use strict';
var server = require( '../server' );
var bookshelf = server.bookshelf;
var Driver = require('../models/driver');

exports.index = server.route(
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/drivers',
        config: {
            handler: function( request, reply ){
               Driver.fetchAll().then( function( drivers ){
                        reply( drivers );
                    } )
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are unable to access it since your driver module is returning a function. In order to access the Driver object you must invoke the Driver function as below to work:

```
var Driver = require('../models/driver')(bookshelf)
```

I would suggest to you to change the model as below because with the approach you use, each time you require the module you are going to initialize the model which is bad.

It is better to initialize only once using the below design.

```
var Bookshelf = require('../server').bookshelf;

var Driver = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'drivers'
});

module.exports = Bookshelf.model('Driver', Driver);
```

And in the controller just require it as below.

```
var Driver = require('../models/driver')
Driver.fetchAll().then( function( drivers ){
  reply( drivers );
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the bonus tip! I noticed something similar but fixed it less efficiently before I saw this answer. Good info though!